# VB.Net Events Practice Help

Tags: vb.net, events

I was given an assignment to "write a program to print only even numbers between 6 and 16 using events", but I don't even know where to begin. The main thing I am having difficulty with understanding in this assignment is how I am supposed to specify that it only print even numbers in the given range of numbers.

Am I going to have to do a Mod2 code for each individual number and have it exclude any with the result of 1? Or is there another piece of code specifically designed for such an occassion? Perhaps there is some type of equation I can have the program read in terms of a variable, which holds the values of 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, and 16? I am just genuinely confused on how this is supposed to be programmed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you written VB .Net programs before?

Comment: @Zian I have a small amount of experience with it, but I know a very limited range of keywords which is the main reason why I have this question. Most of my experience with the programming language is not coding, but rather the fundamentals of programming (such as the Software Development Life Cycle).

Comment: I'm confused about why events are relevant to this problem, or how they could easily be involved, so it's likely that there's something specific in your previous learning materials that is relevant here - we won't be able to guess at that.

Comment: @Ryan James Damien_The_Unbeliever means when should the event occur?

Comment: @Searock I don't exactly know why the events are supposed to be so relevant to this problem, but my teacher was very precise that this was good practice for understanding how events work in code.

Comment: @Ryan James If there no specification when to raise the event, then you can raise the event at your choice. The main concept here is not to print the even numbers, but to understand how events work. Read a nice tutorial on events and let us know if you are stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No offense, but I'm not at all convinced that you are accurately relaying you assignment, but...

Firstly, using MOD is a good starting point, particularly as you are supposedly tying this in with events...

To use events as part of your solution, I would suggest creating a textbox withevents and a handler for textchanged, then in a loop set the txtbox.Text property to the string representation of the loop index (say going from 1 to 20), then inside the textchanded event turn the propery back into an integer, check to see if it's within the proper range and even(using, as you suggested, MOD).

Comment: I understand why you came to the conclusion you did about my broadcasting the assignment details, but it really is that vague and simple. I quite literally copy and pasted the assignment into my original post, as shown in quotes, and then proceeded to ask my series of questions. Something else I thought of to handle this situation was using steps that jump 2 at a time with the range of numbers 6 to 16. Would this work as well? Or is there some reason why that would not be compatible while using events? I thank you greatly for the help you have provided.

Comment: Nevermind that previous comment, I was able to use your information flawlessly to create the coding I needed. I thank you greatly for helping me out here.

Comment: On thinking about, perhaps what your teacher wanted was to have a buttons w

Comment: Maybe your teacher wanted a button to kick everything off.  You might consider structuring it that way if you haven't already.  I'd suggest keeping the separation of UI and calculation, as doing so makes your code more robust and testable.

Answer (score 0):

These Microsoft links are good learning resources:

- [Learning Visual Basic from the Ground Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789086)
- [Getting Started with Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466159)
- [Video How to: Creating Your First Visual Basic Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820886.aspx)
- [Events in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Closer Look: Understanding Properties, Methods, and Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172576%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Events and Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z7x8ys3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I thank you greatly for these links. I know some of the basic information on these pages, but they will all be very helpful to me here.

Answer (score 0):

The following will help you solving a part of the problem:

```
Dim number as Integer = 6
While number <= 16
    // PRINT Goes here ..
    number = number + 2
End While
```

Comment: From what I can tell of the code you provided, the integer will start off at 6 and eventually hit 16 (while not going past because of the less than or equal to sign) while skipping all odd numbers (since it is adding two at a time). Am I correct in this assumption? If so, then this is exactly what I needed and I thank you.